# IE ignoring margins between 2 horizontal divs

Tags: css

I'm putting a ul list in a div which is below a second div. The vertical gap in chrome, ff etc is a little long. So, I'm puting a 10px negative margin on the ul div. Looks great except in IE. With the negative margin, the list is almost overlapping the title text

I have done a lot of reading re inline: block; zoom: 1; position: relative etc, but can't seem to get the page to display right in IE. Bit of a newb on css so specific directions on what has to be applied to what div would be appreciated..

simple for the experts I expect
THANKS
Randall

Comment: please post your code here, or make a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Also: what version of IE and have you specified a DTD?

Comment: Its actually a div inside a div..
HTML
html<div class="PanelFull825">
   <h2>Building a Pond ?</h2>
    <div class="Panel-for-List">
      <ul>
        <li><span class="TextBold"..p you build</a> your pond  </li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    <br/>
    <br/><br/><br/></div>


css
.PanelFull825 {
 clear: none;
 height: auto;
 width: 825px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.Panel-for-List {
 clear: none;
 height: auto;
 width: auto;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: -10px;
 What I added:
 position: relative;
 zoom: 1;
 display: inline;
}

Comment: I'm testing in IE 8 and not working...thanks guys..don't know what a DTD is ....Randall

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [if lte IE(?)] conditional comments to make adjustments to IE only.
A conditional comment link looks like this:

`<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="ie7.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->`

and your link should go in `<head>`, with all your other css links.

**Note**

if you are overriding standing css rules in your IE style sheet you may need to use `!important` etc.

**Edit**

The lte in the conditional comment means less than or equal to. You can remove it completely to target only one IE version.

Comment: thanks -  I get that, but looking for the code to deal with this ignoring of the negative margins. I mean, life is too short to deal with this IE bullshit - trying to go live in the next day or two..

Comment: <!--[if lte IE 8]> <p></p> <![endif]-->   hahaha...works but obviously need to inplement it into css which have trouble doing thanks

Comment: dealing with the negative margins: I just add `margin-?:20?px !important;` to a negative margin in my IE stylesheet, and that negates it. I know what you mean about IE.... I'm just glad IE users are waking up! Glad to be of help!